# Date filter not applied on localhost (but via Jupyter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Need to apply a date filter for my data frame (e.g. showing only data rows between 14/09/2014 and 30/08/2020).

So far, my code looks like this:

```
import dtale
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://manifestoproject.wzb.eu/down/data/2020b/datasets/MPDataset_MPDS2020b.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='edate')
d = dtale.show(df)
df.loc['14/09/2014':'30/08/2020']
d.open_browser()
```

(As you can see, I'm working with d-tale as I'm completely new to coding, but need to analyze mass data for my research project.) The date filter is applied in VSC (I use Jupyter notebook so that I can check and run every step) correctly, it shows the results I need, but the filter is not applied on my localhost page as soon as I run `d.open_browser()`. Do you have any ideas what might be the reason?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should show your data frame on dtale after filtering the data frame

```
df.loc['14/09/2014':'30/08/2020']
d = dtale.show(df)
```

Comment: Already tried that, does not change the result :/ The filter is still not applied

Comment: is your date column index column?

Comment: I think so, used `index_col='edate'` in `pd.read_csv`

Comment: ok found that you should assign your filter data to a variable
`df=df.loc['14/09/2014':'30/08/2020]`

Comment: ufff, you god!! thanks so much for your help --> it worked! it seems there are also results outside the given dates, why is that? It should just show results between the 14/09/2014 and 30/08/2020, but it also shows e.g. 12/09/1965 --> already tried with >= etc. but it's always syntax errors